# Python function for indexing a matrix with two vectors

Tags: python, matrix

Suppose we have a matrix M and two vectors a and b.
Is there a function in Python that returns:
`x = f(M,a,b)` such that `x(i) = M(a(i),b(i))?`

This is of course assuming that the elements in a and b do not exceed the size of M.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(M, a, b):
    return [M[xa, xb] for xa, xb in zip(a, b)]
```

is close to what you ask for.

You didn't specify whether `a` and `b` are the same length or what to do if they aren't -- `zip`, which I'm using here, will just stop when the **shorter** one of them is exhausted (if their lengths differ).

I'm also assuming that by `x(i)` you mean `x[i]` (&c) -- the difference between square brackets (indexing) and ordinary parentheses (function call) is crucial in Python, but thinking in terms of function calls (which is what your Q as posted clearly specifies) makes no sense whatsoever.